# Show PDF with custom styles with wkHTMLtoPDF in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pdf-generation

I've installed [wk HTML to PDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and can show the PDF, but I would like to show my custom styles and scripts. I have tried the following code (I have used them before in other views):

```cs
@Styles.Render("~/Content/recibo.css")
```

and

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/scripts-recibo.css")
```

Comment: How are you generating the html to pass into the PDF conversion?  Make sure the html you generate is referencing your styles directly and they are available at the point you do the conversion.

Comment: I'm using the styles and the scripts just like the other views in the system. And if I return the view like an action, everything works perfectly. But for the pdf don't.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your code just before you convert the html to pdf and examine the html with the built in html debug visualizer, does it look like you want it to or are the styles missing?